# Delete Files in a folder and disregard an existing folder

Tags: python, arcpy

I did a lot of geoprocessing steps and now I like to delete all files including *result*, *result*, *_join*, *_inter*and *reclass* in their name. I can do this with the following

```
import glob
import os
for fl in glob.glob(r"D:\Users\julia\erste_aufg\delete\*result*" ):
    os.remove(fl)

for f2 in glob.glob(r"D:\Users\julia\erste_aufg\delete\*result*" ):
    os.remove(f2)

for f3 in glob.glob(r"D:\Users\julia\erste_aufg\delete\*_join*" ):
    os.remove(f3)

for f4 in glob.glob(r"D:\Users\julia\erste_aufg\delete\*_inter*" ):
    os.remove(f4)

for f5 in glob.glob(r"D:\Users\julia\erste_aufg\delete\*reclass*" ):
    os.remove(f5)
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532498/delete-files-with-python-through-os-shell).

But before deleting I created a resultfolder in the folder(workspace) with the files and copied the results of the geoprocessing steps which I need furthermore to this resultfolder. Because of this resultfolder the code to delete is not working any more. What can I do that the delete-code disregards the resultfolder?

(The code down is just to make the question more clear)

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"env.workspace = r"D:\Users\julia\urban_A_sel""
#new folder
# Set local variables
out_folder_path = env.workspace
out_name = "resultfolder"

# Execute CreateFolder
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(out_folder_path, out_name)
newpath= env.workspace + "\\" + out_name
out_gdb_path = newpath
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_gdb_path, "output.gdb")
outWorkspace= newpath +"\\"+"output.gdb"
resultList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_result*")
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(resultList, outWorkspace)
```

Comment: Could you change the output folder's name to something your delete script wouldn't be interested in -- like `out_name = "datafolder"`?

Comment: Could you clear up what the structure of the files is. I.e. provide an example of say five files in a couple of directories and highlight which you want to keep and which you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you could use os.walk and remove the folder from dirnames. [Python docs show an example of this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), similar to what fluidmotion has but within the traversing itself.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just had to change the name of the “resultfolder” as Erica said.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit clunky, but it seems you could try something like

```
if os.path.split(os.path.dirname(f1))[-1]!='resultfolder':
    os.remove(f1)
```

so that after glob returns a full path, this would strip off the last directory of the path and compare it with 'resultfolder' - if the directory is different, it would remove the file

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I just had to change the name of the “resultfolder” as Erica said.